# Take a picture based on the scale of detection- Python + OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, detect

Below is my code which doing to detect the face via webcam.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade =     cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\OpenCV2.0\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _,f=img.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
         detect_frame = cv2.rectangle(f,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)


    cv2.imshow('img',f)

if cv2.waitKey(25) == 27:
    break



cv2.destroyAllWindows()
img.release()
```

Through this code, I want to take a picture once it realizes the scale of frame changing or the person is moving. After taking the picture, It will save a picture in a file, then continue its job.

May you guys help me the way to solve this case? Thank you too much for your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I've written, what it does is that it first finds the center of the rectangle that we got through face detection. Then it compares the value of the center coordinate after a certain interval of time like 2s, if the value of pixel has changed above a certain threshold it will show that movement is detected. The code worked fine. To improve accuracy you can add more points in the condition whose change in value will indicate movement.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i=1000
c=10 

while 1:
    _, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    #we will increment the value of i after every loop so that we could check value of coordinate after a certain time
    i=i+1

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,150,10),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        #finding the center of the rectangle(around face)
        a=y+h/2
        b=x+w/2

        d = x + w / 2
        if i % 5 == 0:
            print (abs(a - c))
            if (abs(a-c))>9:            #change this value to calibrate
                print("Movement Detected")
            c = y + h / 2

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff

    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

We needed to update value after sometime to compare for which I've used if i%5==0 where i is incremented after every loop

Comment: First of all, I want to thank your answer and your code. I will try to develop the take a image once movement detected as well.

Comment: hey replace if (abs(a-c))>9: with if ((abs(a-c))+abs(b-d))>18:  
                print("Movement Detected")
            c = y + h / 2
            d = x + w / 2 (declare d after movement detected and initialize d to some value as we initialized c)  it will make the difference that now it detects change in both x & y. Let me know if your are having any problem in execution of code

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I have tried the code you gave and "develop" some values in order to get clearer and smoothly. But the problem I got is "it just detects once the "blue frame" (detection frame) is changing that means when I try to move to the right or the left either it does not detect cause the frame didnot change during those actions.
But, any way I would like to give you a code to detect a movement ( not detect a movement via "FACE" ). In case of you want to reference or use it :))